# Flutter Error: Could not find the correct ScopedModel

Tags: dart, flutter, state, flutter-layout, scoped-model

I am trying to create a scopedmodel in my flutter project and I can't seem to figure out why I get the error. What is wrong in this scopedmodel implementation?
I have a home page with bottom navigator. Inside the profile tab, I fetch the list of followers which I need in a widget deep in the tree so I am trying to use scopedmodel.

The model code is

```
class RelationshipsModel extends Model {
        List<Relationship> relations;
        RelationshipsModel(this.relations);
        void add(String name) {
            relations.add(new Relationship("", "", name, name));
            notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

Profile page that creates the scopedmodel is below. Here I get the followers list from Firebase in the state and use it to create the model for the scopedmodel.

```
 class ProfileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ProfileWidgetState createState() => _ProfileWidgetState();
    }

class _ProfileWidgetState extends State<ProfileWidget> {
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUserDetails();
  }
getCurrentUserDetails() async {
_name = await CacheService.getCurrentUser();
var following = await service.getFollowingList(_name);
setState(() {
      this._following = following;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (this._name == null) {
      return new Container(
        child: const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
      );
    }

return  ScopedModel<RelationshipsModel>(
        model: RelationshipsModel(this._following),
        child: Scaffold(
       //more stuff

         background: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  new CarouselWidget(),
                  new Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                    heightFactor: 6.0,
                    child: new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //Here I am creating the a widget that shows the list of followers and following
                        new FollowerInfoWidget(followers: this._followers,
                            following: this._following),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ])),


     )
   );
  }
}
```

The FollowerInfoWidget is below which calls the ProfileWidget or UserWidget based on the clicked user from the list

```
 class _FollowerState extends State<FollowerWidget> {

  Widget buildListTile(BuildContext context, Relationship item) {
    return new MergeSemantics(
      child: new ListTile(

        title: new Text(item.followerId),
        onTap: () async {
          if (item.followerId == await CacheService.getCurrentUser()) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileWidget()),
            );
          }
          else {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                  UserWidget(name: item.followerId)),
            );
          }
        },
        trailing: new Icon(Icons.info, color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The button which is FollowUnFollowWidget is part of the UserWidget

```
    class UserWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  UserWidget(
      {Key key})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _UserWidgetState createState() => _UserWidgetState();
}

class _UserWidgetState extends State<UserWidget> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
//more stuff
 new FollowerInfoWidget(
                              followers: this._followers,
                              following: this._following,
                            ),
                            new FollowUnFollowWidget ()
```

And the widget that has the ScopedModelDescendant is below

```
class FollowUnFollowWidget extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<RelationshipsModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) =>
            FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {}
           //more stuff
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where in the widget tree is `FollowUnFollowWidget`? Is it in the //more stuff section of your `ProfileWidget`?

Comment: No it is invoked from another widget which in turn is invoked from ProfileWidget.
ProfileWidget -> UserWidget -> FollowUnfollowWidget

Comment: Can you show a bit more with your example the Widgets you mentioned.

Comment: So the ProfileWidget represents the user's profile which shows the numbers users being followed and number of followers. These 2 numbers are clickable Text that show all the users in that list. On selection of a user from that list UserWidget is invoked which also has a button to follow/unfollow this user.

I have edited my initial question to add more code

Comment: Added answer, which may be your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code here will push a view which is either a `ProfileWidget` or a `UserWidget`

```
onTap: () async {
      if (item.followerId == await CacheService.getCurrentUser()) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileWidget()),
        );
      }
      else {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
              UserWidget(name: item.followerId)),
        );
      }
    },
```

Since `UserWidget` has the `FollowUnFollowWidget` the use of `ScopedModelDescendant` would not work since there is no `ScopedModel` above it. This `ScopedModel` is only defined with the `ProfileWidget`

Looks like you need to add the `ScopedModel` to either the top of the build method of `UserWidget` or as part of `buildListTile`

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same mistake, the error could also be the context.
In some cases it does not find the Scoped model because the context is not where you start your main ScopedModel

Answer (score 0):

You need add the scopedmodel in main.dart like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return ScopedModel<UserModel>(
        model: UserModel(),
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: "YourApp",
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              body: HomeScreen(),
            )
        )
    );
  }
```