# Error: Could not find the correct ScopedModel

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing an app with many pages, and to manage states I started to use `ScopedModel`, here is my app simple structure:

[image]

my `MainModel()` is:

`class MainModel extends Model with LoginModel, PostsFeedModel, SocialLoginModel, ProfileModel{}`

and I added it to the main material app like this:

```
return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
  model: MainModel(),
  child: new MaterialApp(
```

I can't simply use `ScopedModelDescendant` on any of the child views like :

`child: ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>( ...` I get this error

> Error: Could not find the correct ScopedModel

I have to add `ScopedModel<MainModel>(...` to make it work!

I sow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941568/flutter-error-could-not-find-the-correct-scopedmodel) but I am pretty sure this is possible as I am following a course which it's lecturer uses a very similar structure (pushing new views) and it worked for him.

also as another try to use multiple scoped model I followed scoped model owner's suggestion [here](https://github.com/brianegan/scoped_model/issues/9#issuecomment-413723685) as here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:Sheer/util/SheerDialog.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import '../../models/profile-model.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final uid;

  Profile({@required this.uid});

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profileModel = ScopedModel.of<ProfileModel>(context);
    return profileModel.user.photoURL != ''
      ? Scaffold( ....
```

and it still showing the same error, any help will be appreciated.
thanks and excuse my weak language.

Comment: when importing libraries you should follow one pattern using `import 'package:` or just the name with path without the package keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the way I import the main_model.dart;

in the main.dart I imported it like that : `models/main_model.dart`

in the inner pages I imported it like that : `package:MYAPP/models/main_model.dart`

when I unified the way I called the file, it worked as expected

Thanks to Raof Rahich for his comment